# How can I hide the Paging in the Grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, pagination, custom-admin-grid

I used the Grid to create a report which shows at most 5 rows so I'd like to hide the Paging altogether.  Does anyone know how to hide it?

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Tim

Comment: show relevant codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your grid class add this in the constructor:

```
$this->setPagerVisibility(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

For magento 2, try below in construct method.

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('postGrid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('customer_prescription_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setVarNameFilter('post_filter');
    $this->setFilterVisibility(false); //Filter Visibility is disabled
    $this->setDefaultLimit(100); //Default Pagination is set 100
    $this->setPagerVisibility(false); //Pagination Visibility is disabled
}
```